# Equivalent of SecurityBindingElement.EnableUnsecuredResponse for .net core?

Tags: wcf, .net-core

I'm migrating a bunch of .Net Framework projects to .Net Core 2.1, and the current project uses WCF. I've tried to use the [wcf client for net core](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf), but I'm left with two statements I don't know how to rewrite (element is a BindingElementCollection):

- `elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>().EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;`, EnableUnsecuredResponse is not a property of the dotnet version of SecurityBindingElement
- `elements.Find<MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement>().MaxBufferSize = 200000000;`, MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement does not exist.

Comment: [MTOM](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1810) isn't supported on .NET Core.

Comment: Thank you, I was starting to realise this.. Will it ever be?

Comment: Or is it currently impossible to use .NET Core as a SOAP client for this service? Can I choose to use an "alternative" to MTOM?

Comment: I don't know, perhaps the service offers a non-MTOM endpoint.